# Prove that for any $x,y \in \Bbb R$, we have $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Original question: Prove that for any $x,y \in \Bbb R,$ we have $$||x|- |y||\leq |x-y|.$$ I am confused about how to prove this. Could I simply use an example with real numbers $x$ and $y$, or do I have to prove it formally since it says for any $x$ and $y$? I have no idea how to prove this without a specific example!

Answer (score 1):

Particular examples never prove anything - they only serve as counter examples for false assertions. Use the triangular inequality twice. Use that $$|x| = |x-y+y| \leq |x-y|+|y|,$$so that $|x|-|y| \leq |x-y|$. Repeat this reasoning to conclude that $|y|-|x| \leq |x-y|$.

But what does $-(|x|-|y|)\leq |x-y|$ and $|x|-|y|\leq |x-y|$ imply?

Comment: By symmetry, once is enough.

Comment: Surely. But OP is beginning and I wanted her to realize that on her own, as that might be instructive :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since both sides are positives we can square:
$$
||x|- |y||\leq|x-y| \Leftrightarrow (|x|-|y|)^2\leq (x-y)^2  \Leftrightarrow x^2-2|xy|+y^2\leq x^2-2xy+y^2  \Leftrightarrow \\
 \Leftrightarrow -2|xy|\leq -2xy  \Leftrightarrow |xy|\geq xy
$$
which is obviously true for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your calculations are valid for real numbers only.

Comment: You have to substitute $<$ with $\leq$, otherwise the last inequality is not 'obviously true'

Comment: @ guestDiego: you are right. thanks for noticing. I will edit the post.

Comment: @ Bernard: OP explicitly states that we are dealing with real numbers.